# assistance to with rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want URL to look like `www.example.com/chat/91` but really the page is `www.example.com/room.php?id=91` I searched online for `apache rewrite example` but I didn't see any examples in this format to use,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use this `RewriteRule` in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^chat/([^/]*)$ /room.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.